# Root build.gradle is huge. By what means are these usually decomposed?

Tags: gradle

So I finally have an awesome and fully functional Gradle build. ...but I'm noticing that the root `build.gradle` is pretty big. Several pages. I've done some searching but I don't see any examples of how to decomp one of these to smaller parts. Could I, for example, put nebula dependency management in a different file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
apply from: 'foo.gradle'
apply from: 'bar.gradle'
```